# Save language data in session

Tags: php, twig, multilingual, gettext

Since gettext won't work well, i need to switch to arrays for a multilangual site.

Now i ask myself what's a good way to do that, since i need the language in php files and classes but also in twig templates.

Now i thought that i could just store the array with the language strings (about 500) in the user's session, and could use is everywhere without trouble then.

Is this bad? Do you guys have better ideas, without the need to recode much, since i am under pressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the whole language array in the user's session isn't the best think.
You could store the language i.E. 'en_EN' in the user's session and then load the language data based on the this session.

Comment: Well, i thought of that too, but how should i recive the string then? With a static function call? I thought that is not very fast when every string get's fetched one by one?

Comment: You could either make the variable with the language array global, or write a small abstract class which loads the language file and has got a static function that simply returns the several value of the array identified by the key you sumbit as parameter. Like this:
`Lang::get('teststring');` would return the value of 'teststring'.

Comment: Well it's much work but i think that the solution with the class should be the best "style" ^^

Comment: It's basically something like this: 

`abstract class Lang {

    protected static $language;

    /**
     * Loads a language array into class
     * @param array $pLang Language
     */
    public static function setLanguage($pLang) {
        self::$language = $pLang;
    }

    /**
     * Get a language ressource
     * @param string $pKey Key of ressource.
     * @return string ressource
     */
    public static function get($pKey) {
        return self::$language[$pKey];
    }
}`

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but i never used a abstact class. Isn't it the same as a "normal" class with staatic methods?^^

Comment: No, the difference is, that an abstract can be used without initialization but can contain non-static content. You see it with the language array. It keeps saved in the class for the whole runtime of the PHP script. In other words: It's a kind of class between normal class and normal class with static methods.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work like this, since i cant call static methods from twig. So i would need to make it to a normal class and create a object in order to use it in twig. But then i have the problem that i would need to pass the object to every other class in order to access it. Or am i on the wrong way? :/

Comment: No, using a normal class requires to pass the instance of the class to every other class.

Comment: Well, i saw a another solution for this a while ago, but forgot her. It was a if inside the method which checks if it got called static or not, and depending on that it will use $this or self::. Or something like that.. But i don't know how to do that anymore :/

Comment: Wayne, will try something else :P

Comment: I don't know something like this. It is possible but you have to think about the relation of effort and effect. I would use a more simple method..

Comment: Yeah. Since my code is not that bad, i just found out that i have only one class where i need the translations. I will just create another instance there. Should make not a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to add data to the session that is not relevant to the session.

Just inlude a php file that defines an array with language strings. 
That's the best solution for performance and simplicity.

Maintining that array is a different matter. You could use a translation tool such as https://poeditor.com/. This Tool (and there are others) allows you to export your translations to a PHP array so it gets generated dynamically.

Comment: Yeah i already did this now. It was a stupid ide, i just don't wanted to modify all the code.. But im halth done. I created the translation array manually. How does poeditor know which strings are translation strings?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very good idea, because you multiply the amount of stored text data by the number of users.

Better is to put the various language text snippets into arrays, then store the relevant language code for a given user in the cookie and use it as a key to retrieve the appropriate text at run-time.

Comment: Well, but how should i recive the string then? With a static function call? I thought that is not very fast when every string get's fetched one by one?